# App Script Error - Adding a QR Code formula to script

Tags: qr-code, google-apps-script-editor

I am using the below script to add a QR Code formula copied down my google sheet.
It displays error:

> "Missing ) after argument list".

I tried to look for this but no answer found.

```
function copydownformresponses() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    ss.getRange("F2").setFormula("=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(E2), "", 
    image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&E2)))");

    var lr = ss.getLastRow();
    var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2 , 6 , lr-1);
    ss.getRange("F2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

Looking forward to hearing from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function copydownformresponses() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    ss.getRange("F2").setFormula('=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(E2), "",image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&E2)))');
    var lr = ss.getLastRow();
    var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2 , 6 , lr-1);
    ss.getRange("F2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```